# Stop Application Insights from posting to Debug console

Tags: visual-studio-2013, azure-application-insights

Now I really do quite like the new Application Insights with Visual Studio 2013, and I don't want to remove it. However, it does spam my Debug output quite a lot.

I get rows upon rows of output like

```
Application Insights Telemetry: {"ver":1,"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerformanceCounter","time":"2015-04-23T11:38:03.1252550+01:00","iKey":"758c18d5-055e-48a8-bbcf-9c3301402b2c","tags":{"ai.internal.sdkVersion":"0.13.2.132","ai.application.ver":"Unknown","ai.device.type":"PC","ai.device.id":"Pat-PC","ai.device.oemName":"Dell Inc.","ai.device.model":"Dell XPS430                  ","ai.device.network":"6","ai.device.language":"en-GB","ai.device.machineName":"Pat-PC","ai.device.os":"Windows NT 6.1.7601.65536"},"data":{"type":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerformanceCounterData","item":{"categoryName":"Processor","counterName":"% Processor Time","instanceName":"_Total","value":35.9710731506348,"ver":1}}}
```

This kinda makes it impossible for me to actually use the Debug output for my debug statements. How can I silence Application Insights, or configure Visual Studio to just not show those statements?

Comment: Decompiling .NET assemblies makes life easy, it quickly helped me find [this web page](http://apmtips.com/blog/2015/02/02/developer-mode/).  Set it to *false*.

Comment: Yes! That absolutely did the trick, thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable application insights in debug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32057441/disable-application-insights-in-debug)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hans Passant is right. DeveloperMode is what triggers AI to write events in DebugOutput. Note though that it also forces AI to send data immediately. So if we set it to false data will be batched and sent out once a minute.

Comment: How can we disable the messages but retain the automatic flushing of data?

Comment: @MarkSowul looks like you can turn off just the debug output with `TelemetryDebugWriter.IsTracingDisabled = true`.

Answer (score 6):

To simply turn off these messages, with no other side effects:

```
TelemetryDebugWriter.IsTracingDisabled = true;
```

Comment: One side effect is the 'application insights' pane in visual studio won't receive the output

Comment: Where do I add this in Program.cs?