# Can Application Insight be disabled or enabled in a live application

Tags: azure-application-insights

Is there a way to disable Application Insights in a ASP.NET Web app? Suppose I want to switch off all data collection in an app running in production.

Comment: any specific reason why you want to turn it off?

Comment: Where you hosted application?

Comment: The apps are hosted on premise

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable application insights in debug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32057441/disable-application-insights-in-debug)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if the ikey is in the `ApplicationInsights.config` file, you can remove it from the config file and it should stop sending data.

if the ikey is somewhere else, you'll have to disable via code:

```
TelemetryConfiguraiton.Active.DisableTelemetry
```

see: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/blob/1648ecd5bf32cc151557d15cbb0886cb86e84270/src/Core/Managed/Shared/Extensibility/TelemetryConfiguration.cs#L96

*worst worst* case you could always prevent outbound web requests to `dc.services.visualstudio.com`, where AI would be sending the data.

Comment: Would be nice to have the TelemetryConfiguraiton.Active.DisableTelemetry as an configuration file option

Comment: The Configuration method in the Startup.cs class is a good place to put 'TelemetryConfiguration.Active.DisableTelemetry = true;'.  Also need to add the 'using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;' statement to the usings section at the head of the file, too.