# Remove trace from application insight

Tags: azure, trace, azure-application-insights

I have deployed my project in Azure & using Application Insights. After deployment, I have done some test that why some traces wrote in respective Application Insights.

But, I just want a fresh (without any trace) Application Insights without creating a new Application Insights resource.

Is it possible to remove the previous traces from Application Insights? how?

*Application Insights- system monitor & trace/log viewer at Azure.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to delete any data. It ll auto-clear after retention policy days (I guess 1 or 2 weeks).

See [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32057441/disable-application-insights-in-debug) talking about disabling telemetry while debug/testing.

Btw, You can [vote](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/357324-application-insights/suggestions/19254595-enable-to-clear-data-of-the-resource)  to bring this idea up for implementation.

**Update**:
The idea of deleting/purging data is completed. Now it’s possible to purge the data from AppInsights.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-insights/components/purge?WT.mc_id=DX-MVP-5004422)