# How do I disable Application Insights logging in Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.20.0" and upper?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

I have an Asp.Net Core 6 Web Api.

I added Application Insights to it and I have stored the Connection string in a local Secrets.json file as is recommended.

I don't want to send telemetry when in debug while I am still developing the app.

I want to be able to switch it on and off while I develop.

What is the best way to do it?

The first thing that comes to my mind is to adjust the log level in appsettings.Development.json:

```
"ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "None"
      }
    }
```

I see this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32057441/disable-application-insights-in-debug), but all the answers seem outdated because in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core#configure-the-application-insights-sdk) it is recommended to make the configurations in appsettings.json, NOT in the code.

Is there a better alternative for Asp.net Core 6 and Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.20.0" than putting the LogLevel to none?

**Edit:** I use Secrets.json file as recommended [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=windows&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-2.2) to store the connection string locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just not set the instrumentation key in debug/development mode so the telemetry is not send to azure but still visible in the [Visual Studio tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/visual-studio)

[image]

Comment: I use local Secrets.json file to store the Connection string locally - as it is recommended for safer local development. In my case how should I proceed to see telemetry only locally?

Comment: Just comment out the connection string in secrets.json file? @peter-bons

Comment: @MiBuena yes that will do the trick